# Standards related with SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Are there any better standard to implement Single Sign On other than Security Assertion Markup Language(SAML)?If any, which is best for authentication?

Comment: This question was answered.  Please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @T-Heron users are not required to accept answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three common standards.

- WS-Fed
- SAML
- OpenID Connect / OAuth

None are "better" than others. It depends on the use case.

SAML / WS-Fed are more for enterprise and browsers.

OIDC is better for native devices (Non-browser e.g. desktop, mobile) and for REST (web API).

But they all handle authentication and most identity providers support all three.

Comment: Good question. This was a solid, and correct answer.  Don't know why the OP hasn't accepted it yet.